# Hibernate PostUpdateEvent null old state

Tags: java, hibernate

With Hibernate (4.1.7.Final) I want to do certain things only when given property of an entity is updated, so I implement PostUpdateEvent and I want to check:

```
@Override
public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
   int[] dirtyProperties = event.getDirtyProperties();
   ...
```

But this is null, the same with event.getOldState();
The object exists in db, the transaction was commited before, the session was flushed.

Anyway, if onUpdate is fired there must have been some old object - how are those null values possible?

Answer (score 2):

Made sure you load the entity into the session first. I got the same issue. It worked for me after I added code to load the entity into the session before making updates to the entity. 
For example,

```
session.load(Entity.class, entity.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that your version contains the bug described here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7543
?

Comment: Thx for answer after this time;-) There is Fix Version/s: 4.1.7 so my version shouldn't be affected by that... but I'll check yet when I'm back to that.